# ubuntu is not booting, after dual boot installation with windows 7

Tags: 12.04, boot, grub2, dual-boot, windows-7

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I repair grub? (How to get Ubuntu back after installing Windows?)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows)

Recently i bought a lenovo u410 ultrabook. It has given along with windows 7 and 4 primary partitions. So to install ubuntu 12.04 i removed one of the primary partition and made it as extended partition. In that extended partition, i allocated memory for the **swap** and **root (/)** directory and then installed the ubuntu. After that by using **EasyBCD** tool, added ubuntu to the boot menu in grub2. So when i try to boot into ubuntu it is showing **grub>** prompt only. From there how can i boot into ubuntu.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you explain why you had to use a software like EasyBCD? Wasn't Grub installed correctly by Ubuntu?

Comment: yes, after installation ubuntu, it is not showing in booting menu, so by reading some threads i used it.

Comment: "it is not showing in booting menu" ← do you mean that the system booted directly in Windows? Or that it showed an error (and if so, which error)? Sorry for insisting, but these information are important to understand your problem.

Comment: `UEFI`... Please if possible, look in `BIOS` if there's is an option to switch from `UEFI` to `BIOS legacy` or something similar. I had the same problem on my `Acer` laptop. This option should be available in the same place where you choose the boot order.

Comment: @AndreaCorbellini: At boot time windows boot manager showing only windows OS to select.

Comment: @Melon: In boot options there is only UEFI Boot option and it is set to enabled. There is nothing like BIOS legacy.

Comment: @Kranthi - try to disable it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the `Recommended Repair` of this little tool: Boot-Repair https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

[image]

Comment: Great :) Please don't forget to validate the answer (click the icon under the arrows)